# To show A FirstViewController On Call of a method from SecondViewController in Iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios4

Actually I am Making an Alarm app. In that When i set the Time The UILocalNotification event happens at that time and it calls the method of AppDelegate class i.e didReceiveNotifications method. In this method i have written a code to call a method of SetViewController (showReminder method) and now in this method i want that it should show a NewViewController i.e TimeViewController as i have to show animation when the Alarm Invokes.

I need this as When Alarm invokes i have setted a Action sheet to appear but i wanted to show animation also.Action sheet appears in all views But the animation can be Shown in only particular view, that's why i need to show A different ViewController.

Here is the code for what i am trying :-
I have tried al these also like PresentModalViewController, dismissModalViewController, AddSubview, remove superView... but result are negative :(  what should i do..?

Almost Whole CODE:--

**AppDelegate Class :-**

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {
    if (notification){
        NSLog(@"In did Notification");
        NSString *reminderText = [notification.userInfo objectForKey:kRemindMeNotificationDataKey];
        [viewController showReminder:reminderText];
        application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
    }
}
```

setViewController.h :-

```
@interface SetAlarmViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,UITextFieldDelegate,UIActionSheetDelegate>{

    IBOutlet UITableView *tableview;
    IBOutlet UIDatePicker *datePicker;
    IBOutlet UITextField *eventText;
    TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView *scrollView;

    IBOutlet UINavigationBar *titleBar;
    IBOutlet UIButton *setAlarmButton;
    AVAudioPlayer *player;
    int index;
    The420DudeAppDelegate *appDelegate;
    TimeViewController *viewController;

   IBOutlet UIImageView *animatedImages;

    NSMutableArray *imageArray;
    AVPlayerItem *player1,*player3;
    AVPlayerItem *player2,*player4;
    AVQueuePlayer *queuePlayer;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *animatedImages;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tableview;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *datePicker;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *eventText;
@property (nonatomic, retain) TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView *scrollView;

@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationBar *titleBar;
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *setAlarmButton;
@property(nonatomic) UIReturnKeyType returnKeyType;  

@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet TimeViewController *viewController;

- (IBAction) scheduleAlarm:(id)sender;
- (void)showReminder:(NSString *)text;
-(IBAction)onTapHome;

-(IBAction)onTapChange:(id)sender;

@end
```

SetViewController.m :-

```
@synthesize datePicker,tableview, eventText,titleBar,setAlarmButton,returnKeyType,scrollView,animatedImages,viewController;


// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    appDelegate = (The420DudeAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    eventText.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;

    viewController = [[TimeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TimeViewController" bundle:nil];

    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    [datePicker setDate:now animated:YES];
    eventText.delegate = self;
    index = 0;

    NSString *path1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"inhale" ofType:@"mp3"];
    NSURL *url1 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path1];
    player1 = [[AVPlayerItem alloc]initWithURL:url1];

    NSString *path3 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sound1" ofType:@"wav"];
    NSURL *url3 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path3];
    player3 = [[AVPlayerItem alloc]initWithURL:url3];

    NSString *path2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"exhale" ofType:@"mp3"];
    NSURL *url2 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path2];
    player2 = [[AVPlayerItem alloc]initWithURL:url2];

    NSString *path4 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Dude" ofType:@"mp3"];
    NSURL *url4 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path4];
    player4 = [[AVPlayerItem alloc]initWithURL:url4];


    NSArray *items = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:player1,player3,player2,player4,nil];
    queuePlayer = [[AVQueuePlayer alloc] initWithItems:items];    

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(playEnded) name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:player4];



}

-(void)onAlarmInvoke
{
    animatedImages = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100)];
    animatedImages.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [animatedImages setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
    [self.view addSubview : animatedImages];

    [queuePlayer play];    

    // Array to hold jpg images
    imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:IMAGE_COUNT];

    // Build array of images, cycling through image names
    for (int i = 1; i <= IMAGE_COUNT; i++)
        [imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"animation(%d).jpg", i]]];

    animatedImages.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithArray:imageArray];

    // One cycle through all the images takes 1.0 seconds
    animatedImages.animationDuration = 12.0;

    // Repeat foreverlight electro / 4 sec.
    animatedImages.animationRepeatCount = -1;

    // Add subview and make window visible
    //  [self.view addSubview:animatedImages];

    animatedImages.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:imageArray.count - 1];

    // Start it up
    [animatedImages startAnimating];



    // Wait 5 seconds, then stop animation
    [self performSelector:@selector(stopAnimation) withObject:nil afterDelay:15000];

}

-(void)playEnded
{   
    [self performSelector:@selector(playNextItem) withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0];
}

-(void)playNextItem
{
    [queuePlayer play];
}
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [scrollView adjustOffsetToIdealIfNeeded];
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:YES];
    [self.tableview reloadData];
}

- (IBAction) scheduleAlarm:(id)sender {
    [eventText resignFirstResponder];

    // Get the current date
    NSDate *pickerDate = [self.datePicker date];

    //   NSDate *selectedDate = [datePicker date]; // you don't need to alloc-init the variable first
    NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];  
    NSDateComponents *dc = [cal components: (NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit) fromDate:pickerDate];
    pickerDate = [cal dateFromComponents:dc]; 

    NSLog(@"%@ is the date in picker date",pickerDate);

    UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    if (localNotif == nil)
        return;
    localNotif.fireDate = pickerDate;
    //  NSLog(@"%@",localNotif.fireDate);
    localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    //  NSLog(@"%@",localNotif.timeZone);

    // Notification details
    localNotif.alertBody = [eventText text];

    // Set the action button
    localNotif.alertAction = @"Show me";
    localNotif.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
    localNotif.soundName = @"jet.wav";
    // Specify custom data for the notification
    NSDictionary *userDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:eventText.text
                                                         forKey:kRemindMeNotificationDataKey];
    localNotif.userInfo = userDict;

    // Schedule the notification
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
    [localNotif release];

    [self.tableview reloadData];
    eventText.text = @"";

    viewController = [[TimeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TimeViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    index = indexPath.row;
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning!!!" 
                                                        message:@"Are you sure you want to Delete???" delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                              otherButtonTitles:@"Ok",nil];
    [alertView show];
    [alertView release];

}
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSArray *notificationArray = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];
    UILocalNotification *notify = [notificationArray objectAtIndex:index];

    if(buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        // Do Nothing on Tapping Cancel...
    }
    if(buttonIndex ==1)
    {
        if(notify)
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:notify];
    }
    [self.tableview reloadData];
}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    // Configure the cell...

    NSArray *notificationArray = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];
    UILocalNotification *notif = [notificationArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [cell.textLabel setText:notif.alertBody];
    [cell.detailTextLabel setText:[notif.fireDate description]];    
    return cell;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    datePicker = nil;
    tableview = nil;
    eventText = nil;
    [self setScrollView:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];

}

- (void)showReminder:(NSString *)text {

    [self onAlarmInvoke];

    [self.view addSubview:viewController.view];

    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [actionSheet setActionSheetStyle:UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent];
    CGRect rect = self.view.frame;
   // if(rect.origin.y <= 480)
  //      rect.origin.y +=20;

    self.view.frame = rect;
    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
    [actionSheet release];


}
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{

    if(buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        [player stop];
        NSLog(@"OK Tapped");
    }
    if(buttonIndex ==  1)
    {
        [player stop];
        NSLog(@"Cancel Tapped");
    }

}

-(IBAction)onTapHome{
    viewController = [[TimeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TimeViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
    [datePicker release];
    [tableview release];
    [eventText release];
    [scrollView release];
}
-(IBAction)onTapChange:(id)sender{

    SetTimeViewController *viewC = [[SetTimeViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SetTimeViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:viewC animated:YES];
}
@end
```

Comment: sorry if i didn't got you but [self.view removeFromSubview]; should solve

Comment: No dude... Its not.. I have tried all varieties :P like PresentModalViewController, dismissModalViewController, AddSubview, remove superView...  but negative result. :(

Comment: In you appDelegate, is your viewController already alloc'ed and init'ed?

Comment: Yes... If you want i can paste my whole code.. its not big.. i will do it on Monday. as i am not at my desk now.

Comment: Updated the Question to the whole Question...

Comment: let me try to get this right... what is it that you want? : that upon alarm, show an animation and pop a uiactionsheet. If this is so, then what is already working?

Comment: ya u got it right... but what i had written is not working.. :( What i am doing wrong.. or what should i do then.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your viewController is probably showing the view, but without the SetViewController's view on the screen you can't see it. Your going to have to first go to the SetViewController and then present your TimeViewController. Is this right, you want to show the SetViewController but call the showReminder: method right away? But only from the didReceiveLocalNotification:.

If this is the case, set a flag,and a text property in your SetViewControllers .h,

```
BOOL isFromNotification;
NSString *notifText;
```

and present the SetViewController,and set the flag

```
SetViewController *setViewController = [SetViewController alloc]........
setViewController.isFromNotification = YES;
setViewController.notifText = reminderText;
[self presentModalViewController animated:YES}
```

and then in the viewDidAppear: of SetViewController

```
if(isFromNotification = YES){
  [self showReminders:notifText];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I got you right ,

upon notification you would like to show animation on a new view and then show the action sheet ?

Right now you call from appdelegate

```
[viewController showReminder:reminderText];
```

which by the way should be self.viewcontroller or _viewcontroller for the actually retained object

In showreminder you call

animation, which in itself adds a subview and by the way is running in the same thread , ie in serial.
and then you add the viewcontroller again as a subview.
and then you try to add the actionsheet from parent to the subview(viewcontroller), when actionsheet should probably be in the viewcontroller itself.

Did i get that right ?

No sure really whats breaking down, could be on several areas, as pointed out above.

I would :
make sure you call the retained objects through valid pointers ( using self for instance)
have a viewcontroller that you present modal as a subview that show animations on a separate thread (performselectoronthread) and have the actionsheet on that.
Then if you need to call the parent, you setup a delegate or you do the ugly way.

```
self.yourviewcontroller.myParentObj = self
```

ie set a yourviewcontroller pointer on the sub viewcontroller, which you can then openly call like

```
[self.myParentObj whatevermethod_you_have_in_parent];
```

But then again I write this from top of my head..